# Mysql access denied when connect via ssh port forwarding

Tags: mysql, ssh, portforwarding

I need to access to a mysql database via ssh port forwarding.

I create the forwarding like this:

```
 ssh -n -N -f -L 3308:127.0.0.1:3306 <user@ipaddress>
```

when connecting I get the error access denied (Error 1045)

When logging into the remote computer with ssh and than try to connect to the database everything works fine.

UPDATE: the database is hosted within a docker container locally. composer file:

```
mysql_XXX:
image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
container_name: mysql_XXX
command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci --init-connect='SET NAMES UTF8;' --skip-character-set-client-handshake --lower-case-table-names=2
restart: always
ports:
  - 3306:3306
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXX
  - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
  - LOWER_CASE_TABLE_NAMES=2
volumes:
  - /home/ubuntu/{path}/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Because I need to access the DB with a python script I need the port forwarding solution.

UPDATE:
The solution was to set

```
 bind-address: 0.0.0.0
```

at the mysqld.cnf

Comment: did you setup remote mysql access on the other server?

Comment: try looking at this doc and try to implement this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-remote-database-to-optimize-site-performance-with-mysql

Comment: @unixmiah yes I configured within the docker composer file environment MYSQL_ROOT_PATH=%

Comment: I do not need to setup a Wordpress, I only need the database.

Comment: so ignore the wordpress related stuff, then. The rest of unixmiah's link is likely still relevant.

Comment: @ADyson the whole article is not addressing ssh port forwarding so it does not address my issue.

Comment: sorry I had misunderstood, it was about remote access rather than SSH, I see.